# Некорректные стили AlertDialog на API 18

Tags: java, android

Сабж. Код activity:

```
package com.gobonus.gobonus;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class InternetDisabled extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_internet_disabled);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);

        builder.setTitle(R.string.title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.err_503);

        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gobonus.gobonus">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/welcomeActivivty">
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/GB"
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InternetDisabled"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".CabinetActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cabinet"
            android:theme="@style/GB_Green.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CabinetActivityy"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cabinet_activityy"
            android:theme="@style/GB_Green.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Стиль (без указания версии api, лежит в /values/styles.xml):

```
<!--alert dialog-->
    <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>
    </style>
```

Логи:

```
03-28 06:26:57.116 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-28 06:26:57.700 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-28 06:26:57.708 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-28 06:26:57.712 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18933: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-28 06:26:57.724 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-28 06:26:57.724 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-28 06:26:57.728 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18937: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-28 06:26:57.728 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-28 06:26:58.052 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 117K, 7% free 2549K/2732K, paused 42ms, total 43ms
03-28 06:26:58.252 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 10.460MB for 8294412-byte allocation
03-28 06:26:58.276 32659-32668/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 10649K/10836K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
03-28 06:26:58.376 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-28 06:26:58.380 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 437: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-28 06:26:58.380 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-28 06:26:58.380 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-28 06:26:58.384 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 459: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-28 06:26:58.384 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-28 06:26:58.428 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/session token: 1459159385SmSrCAoutWNuhV6wwE4CuLDIUaOagoAjv1wQQ60FM8cCBiAuqzje5wczn5LgpngkodUSDQRC7MqwOpEAIgewSLJFditHi32g3OPDCdk1wSYjWa
03-28 06:26:58.444 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 23996 (UTF_8) in Ljava/nio/charset/StandardCharsets;
03-28 06:26:58.448 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x002f
03-28 06:26:58.488 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
03-28 06:26:58.532 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
03-28 06:26:58.532 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
03-28 06:26:58.612 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 06:26:58.612 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
03-28 06:26:58.620 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
03-28 06:26:58.624 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-28 06:26:58.680 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 06:26:59.424 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-28 06:26:59.468 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to api.project.localhost/192.168.2.21 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-28 06:26:59.480 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
03-28 06:26:59.496 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-28 06:26:59.508 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-28 06:26:59.532 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-28 06:26:59.532 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
03-28 06:26:59.536 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-28 06:26:59.536 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
03-28 06:26:59.536 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
03-28 06:26:59.536 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-28 06:26:59.536 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
03-28 06:26:59.540 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
03-28 06:26:59.540 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
03-28 06:26:59.540 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
03-28 06:26:59.540 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
03-28 06:26:59.540 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at com.gobonus.gobonus.Request.<init>(Request.java:75)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(WelcomeActivity.java:88)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity$AsyncRequest.doInBackground(WelcomeActivity.java:78)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-28 06:26:59.544 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-28 06:26:59.548 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-28 06:26:59.548 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
03-28 06:26:59.548 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-28 06:26:59.548 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-28 06:26:59.548 32659-32695/com.gobonus.gobonus W/System.err:    ... 23 more
03-28 06:26:59.924 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 06:26:59.964 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 06:27:00.328 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 06:27:00.368 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 06:27:00.724 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus E/WindowManager: Activity com.gobonus.gobonus.InternetDisabled has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52b2b784 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-580,232} that was originally added here
                                                                    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.gobonus.gobonus.InternetDisabled has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52b2b784 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-580,232} that was originally added here
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
                                                                        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
                                                                        at com.gobonus.gobonus.InternetDisabled.onCreate(InternetDisabled.java:29)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 06:27:00.828 32659-32659/com.gobonus.gobonus E/WindowManager: Activity com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{526ee55c V.E..... R......D 0,0-479,96} that was originally added here
                                                                    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{526ee55c V.E..... R......D 0,0-479,96} that was originally added here
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
                                                                        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
                                                                        at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
                                                                        at com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity.showProgress(WelcomeActivity.java:68)
                                                                        at com.gobonus.gobonus.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:43)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

На API 18 (4.3) я получаю вот такое некрасивое окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На API 22 все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так? И как это решить? Тестил только на API 18 и 22

**UPD:** Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gobonus.gobonus.InternetDisabled">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Скорей всего стиль не подрубился. Он у Вас описан только в styles-v21?

Comment: он у меня описан в основном styles.xml

Comment: Добавьте прозрачный фон в стиль диалога: `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло. К тому же, пропала тень на API22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Вас по всей видимости импорт не из библиотеки поддержки:

> `import android.app.AlertDialog;`

Вот и получается, что на API 18 используется родной `AlertDialog`.

Замените его на:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

**UPD**

Для добавления тени в `pre-lollipop`, необходимо в стиль `AlertDialog`'a добавить следующую строку:

```
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame</item>
```

Значение данного атрибута естественно можно подобрать на свой вкус и цвет.

Comment: Спасибо! Но остались некоторые неприятные мелочи, например нет тени и текст не такой жирный. http://i.imgur.com/vkd8eew.png

Comment: @Андрей смотрите обновление ответа